# html lang with css hyphens

Tags: html, css, lang, word-break

I have added the following css properties to my html

```
 word-break: break-word;
 hyphens: auto;
```

and set the html lang attribute to "de".

The word break happens as expected

```
Deutsches Ipsum Dolor meliore 
Handtasche et Köln Te Eichhörn-
chen utamur zu spät Exerci Sieben-
tausendzweihundertvierundfünfzig 
eu Erbsenzähler
```

When I remove the hyphens css attribute the word-break is totally different

```
Deutsches Ipsum Dolor meliore 
Handtasche et Köln Te 
Eichhörnchen utamur zu spät 
Exerci 
Siebentausendzweihundertvierundfünfzig 
eu Erbsenzähler
```

I want to understand why word-break doesn't break appropriately without the hyphens. Also here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ngrx8y24/

Comment: Why would you want that? How do you recognize that it's one word if nothing connects the parts? You could do this by manually inserting `<wbr>` elements at every point you would have the word break up. I suppose you should also set `hyphens: none;`

Comment: hyphens: none; doesn't fix it for me. Actually , I wouldn't want it too. But the issue is I need to understand why this is happening. I would expect word-break to break the word appropriately.

Comment: Why would you expect that behaviour? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the lang="de" attribute when combined with the css hyphens:auto has its own line breaking rules, but when you add the css word-break, then that overrides the built-in dutch+hyphens line breaking rules.

See the last example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#examples

EDIT: overflow-wrap:anywhere appears to make lang="en-US" wrap with hyphens, but does not add an initial hyphen to long capitalized words like lang="de" does.

EXAMPLES:

```html
<p style="clear:both; width: 160px; margin: 2px; background: gold; hyphens: auto; overflow-wrap:anywhere;" lang="de">They say the fishing is excellent at
  Lake <em>Chargoggagoggmanchauggagoggchaubunagungamaugg</em>,
  though I've never been there myself. (<code>hyphens</code>, German rules)</p>
 
<p style="clear:both; width: 160px; margin: 2px; background: gold; hyphens: auto; overflow-wrap:anywhere;" lang="en-US">They say the fishing is excellent at
  Lake <em>Chargoggagoggmanchauggagoggchaubunagungamaugg</em>,
  though I've never been there myself. (<code>hyphens</code>, english-US rules)</p>
```